# @firebase/testing - How to call `initializeTestApp` with auth.providerId?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

For example, I have these rules:

```
 match /users/{userId} {
   allow create: if isCurrentUser(userId) 
     && request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider != 'anonymous';
   allow update: if isCurrentUser(userId);
 }

 function isCurrentUser(userId){
   return request.auth.uid == userId;
 }
```

I am trying to add unit tests for it and initialize the app this way:

```
const firebase = require("@firebase/testing");

const app = firebase
    .initializeTestApp({
      projectId: "some-firestore-emulator",
      auth: {
        uid: "bohdan",

        // case 1
        token: {
          firebase: {
            sign_in_provider: "google.com"
          }
        },

        // case 2
        providerData: {
          providerId: "google.com"
        },

        //case 3
        providerId: "google.com"
      }
    })
```

but it fails when I am trying to create a document:

```
app.firestore().collections("users").doc("bohdan").set({ name: "Bohdan" })
```

I have this error:

```
FirebaseError: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: 
Property firebase is undefined on object. for 'create' @ L15
```

How to run `initializeTestApp` and successfully create a document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`app.firestore().collections("users").set({ name: "Bohdan" })` is wrong.

You should specify Document ID which is same value `request.auth.uid`. Like this.

`app.firestore().collection("users").doc("bohdan").set({ name: "Bohdan" })`

Could you check Documents and my firebase testing samples?

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth
- https://github.com/zkohi/firebase-testing-samples
- [https://github.com/zkohi/firebase-testing-samples/blob/master/**tests**/firestore.rules.test.ts](https://github.com/zkohi/firebase-testing-samples/blob/master/__tests__/firestore.rules.test.ts)

I tried. Change `initializeTestApp()` arg from `auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider` to `auth.firebase.sign_in_provider`.

```
const app = firebase
    .initializeTestApp({
      projectId: "some-firestore-emulator",
      auth: {
        uid: "bohdan",
        // // case 1
        // token: {
        //   firebase: {
        //     sign_in_provider: "google.com"
        //   }
        //},
        firebase: {
          sign_in_provider: "google.com"
        }   
      }
    })
```

Could you check the following links?

- https://github.com/zkohi/firebase-testing-samples/tree/sign_in_provider
- https://github.com/zkohi/firebase-testing-samples/commit/5952aa86c38bcc45102214208c7b1dfd23914731

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, fixed it. Thank you! 
But I don't know how to resolve a problem and add `sign_in_provider` value to the auth. Your `defaultAuth` and `anotherUidAuth` doesn't include this value. Do you know the solution for it?

Comment: WOW, the solution looks pretty simple, I don't understand why I didn't try that. Thank you Zkohi!